# Is it possible to set up custom dev domains for multiple localhost projects?

Tags: node.js, url, localhost

I'm currently working on several Node based projects and find myself with several `localhost:xxxx` instances. This makes it tough to remember which is which.. Was the client on `localhost:3000` while service A is on `localhost:3030`? etc

I also use WakaTime to track time spent per project and having a custom domain for each would make that setup work *much* more easily.

I have been searching around for quite some time today and can't seem to find any ideas on this that don't depend on Apache.

---

#### What I hope to achieve:

- Visiting `projectA.dev` would serve the app just as it would if I had hit `localhost:3000`. e.g. the browser would navigate to `client.dev/#/account` and I would see the site.

  - Visiting `projectB.dev` would serve the app just as it would if hitting `localhost:3030` (notice different port)
  - etc....

#### My setup details:

- OSX El Capitan
- Angular project using Gulp/BrowserSync/Webpack built with [generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular/)

---

As it stands now, it seems that my only option would setting up [ngrok tunnels with specific subdomains](https://ngrok.com/docs#subdomain)... hoping someone out there with experience on this has words of wisdom..

---

Edit: I did find an [SO question](https://serverfault.com/questions/574116/hostname-to-localhost-with-port-osx) that is trying to solve the same type of issue. Unfortunately I don't have the ability to assign multiple IP address to my machine at work.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your etc/hosts file you can assign an arbitrary host name to be set to 127.0.0.1.
Open up /etc/hosts in your favorite text editor and add this line:

```
127.0.0.1   www.example.com
```

Unsure of how to avoid specifying the port in the HTTP requests you make to example.com, but if you must avoid specifying that at the request level, you could run nodejs as root to make it listen on port 80.

Edit: After editing /etc/hosts, you may already have the DNS request for that domain cached. You can clear the cached entry by running this on the command line.

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```